# Getting info about a Virtual file system

Tags: linux, ext3, df

I have created a Virtual ext3 partition on a armv7 machine with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./system.img bs=1000000 count=200
mkfs.ext2 ./system.img
tune2fs -j ./system.img
```

Now I need to get info about this fs like total space, free space and used space. How can I do this without mounting the fs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tune2fs` will display filesystem information with the `-l` option.

```
> /sbin/tune2fs -l ./tmpfile
tune2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          da61d942-4e9f-4c29-9f20-ab809fb90fbf
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              128
Block count:              1024
Reserved block count:     51
Free blocks:              986                # free space
Free inodes:              117
First block:              1
Block size:               1024
Fragment size:            1024
Reserved GDT blocks:      3
Blocks per group:         8192
Fragments per group:      8192
Inodes per group:         128
Inode blocks per group:   16
...
```